# WPF Ribbon collapse and expand programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, ribbon

With the latest (October 2010) WPF Ribbon libraries, there exists a menu item to minimize/maximize (or collapse/expand, if you prefer) the ribbon control.

Does anyone know if there's also a way to hook into the events that control this behaviour so that it could be controlled programmatically from separate UI?
Or, better yet, is there a way to get a collapse/expand button to display in the ribbon like the 2010 Office apps do?

Answer (score 7):

You can use the boolean property [`IsMinimized`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windows.controls.ribbon.ribbon.isminimized.aspx) on the `Ribbon` class to show/hide the ribbon itself. It is a dependency property, so you can bind to its value to support the scenarios you describe.

As far as I know, the default template does not have a show/hide button, like Office does, but it shouldn't be too hard to modify the template (using Blend) to add one.

Comment: Thanks. I've tapped into that property and also the SizeChanged event on the ribbon itself.
I'll probably hold off on modifying the template.

Answer (score 1):

If what you need is know when the bar gets minimized (this happens when you double click a tab header) you could hook to the `IsMinimizedChanged` event, but er.. it is missing.
Hopefully it is a `DependencyProperty` so you can successfully hook to any `DependencyProperty` change this way:

`DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(Ribbon.IsMinimizedProperty, typeof(Ribbon))
    .AddValueChanged(ribbon, (o, args) => /* your code here */);`

What I wanted to do (and hence got here) is to prevent it from minimizing when double clicking the header so I ended up using this code:

`DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(Ribbon.IsMinimizedProperty, typeof(Ribbon))
    .AddValueChanged(ribbon, (o, args) => ribbon.IsMinimized = false);`

Is not so fancy but gets the job done.

Answer (score 0):

Add a toggle button(simple button and set its content to v or ^ depending upon the operation requested) and then you can use ContentControl in button click to fulfill your requirement:

```
     ContentControl contentControl = FindVisualChildataBankyName<ContentControl>(rbnName, "mainItemsPresenterHost");
     contentControl.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
```

Use contentControl.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible; in order to maximize the ribbon